# Probability and expected gain

Tags: probability

So i've been stuck on this for some time now.
Ms. Hardsell, an insurance agent, offers a 1-year term life insurance policy to males in a particular age category. The cost of the insurance is $30 thousand dollars of coverage. According to actuarial tables, the probability that a male in this category will die within the next year is 0.005.

i) What is the expected gain for the insurer for each thousand dollars of coverage?

ii)If insurance is sold only in multiples of 1000 dollars and if the overheads for writing such a policy are $70, what is the minimum amount of insurance that Ms Hardsell should sell in a policy in order to have a positive expected gain?
Do i use the binomial table to calculate expected gain or what?

Comment: What did you try? Why are you stuck?

Comment: For the first part, are they asking what the insurer will gain if they dont die? I tried 1-0.005=0.995, then multiplied that by the insurance which resulted in a totally different answer and was incorrect

Comment: @SatishRamanathan No the answer is apparently $25

Comment: From what you wrote, I'm unsure about some quantities. What is the cost of buying this insurance? If the insurance is bought and the client dies within a year, how much is paid to his family?

Comment: @madprob that is the exact question, no further details are provided.

Comment: iT IS THEN VERY SIMPLE. $ (30-0.005*1000) = 25$

Comment: From what @SatishRamanathan wrote, it seems that the premium of the insurance is $30$ and the coverage is $1000$. However, there seems to be a typo in what you wrote.

Comment: IT IS 30 PER THOUSAND DOLLAR COVERAGE SHE LEFT "per"

Comment: Im so sorry! It is actually 30/ thousand!  Thanks! Any ideas on the second part?

Comment: Why did you minus 0.005 from 30?

Comment: I did not subtract 0.005 from 30.  The cost for the buyer is the premium for the company and it is 30.  If he dies with a probability of 0.005, then the company would have to pay $1000.  Thus mutiply 0.005 times 1000 that is the expected loss the company would incur. Now the gain is 30 the premium minus the expected loss and hence you get 25

Comment: Satish showed that, for every $1000$ dollars of coverage, Ms. Hardsell gains on average $25$. How many thousands of dollars of coverage must she sell in order for her expected gain to be larger than $70$?

Comment: @SatishRamanathan That was a really good explanation! Any ideas on the second part?

Comment: @madprob so 1000*70/25? But the answer comes out 2800 when the right answer is 3000?

Comment: Indeed, but the question says that Ms. Hardsell can sell only multiples of $1000$. Since $70/25$ is not an integer, she must sell a little more than that.

Comment: @madprob How do i decide how much more?

Comment: So 75 to make it an integer of 3? Yes, that gives the right answer, thank you!!!

Comment: @Marie Anne, before you forgot to give the correct wordings, I assumed something and came up with an answer which might be helpful not now but later in your course.  Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Let us compute the gain for each year to be $G_1, G_2,...$.  Assume that the premium is $30 for 10 years.

Now $G_1 = 30$ premium with a probability of not dying (0.995) - a loss of $1000 with a probability of dying (0.005).

Thus the gain for the first year $G_1 = (0.995\times30 -0.005\times 1000)$

Gain for the second year $G_2$ is calculated by computing the probability of dying and not dying the second year given he did not die the first year.

Thus $G_2 = (0.995\times 0.995 \times 30 - 0.995\times 0.005 \times 1000) $

Now Expected Gain G = $G_1 + 2.G_2 + 3.G_3 +\cdots +10.G_{10}$

Split this Expected Gain into two streams.

1 Stream $= 30(0.995+2\times.995^2+3\times.995^3+\cdots+10\times0.995^{10})$

2 Stream $= 1000(.005+2\times.995\times0.005+3\times0.995^2\times 0.005+\cdots+10\times 0.995^9\times 0.005)$

1 Stream $= 30\times0.995(1+2\times0.995+3\times 0.995^2+\cdots+10\times0.995^9)$

2 Stream $= 1000\times0.005(1+2\times 0.995+3\times 0.995^2+\cdots+10\times0.995^9)$

$ S = 1+2\times 0.995+3\times 0.995^2+\cdots+10*0.995^9)$

$0.995S = 0.995 +2\times 0.995^2+\cdots+10*0.995^{10})$

Subtract these two

$0.005 S = 1+0.995+.995^2+\cdots+9\times0.995^9- 10\times0.996^{10}= \frac{1 - 0.995^10}{.005} - 10\times.995^{10} = 0.267$

$S =53.37$

1 Stream $= 30\times0.995\times53.37 = 1593$

2 Stream $= 1000\times0.005\times 53.37 = 267$

Expected Gain over 10 years$ = 1593-267 = 1326$